# UITextView Delegates Behaving Differently with Custom iOS Keyboards (SwiftKey)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uikeyboard, uitextviewdelegate

Using the `shouldChangeTextInRange` delegate to detect certain phrases when typed in a `UITextView`gives different `range` and `text` values when alternating between the stock keyboard and custom keyboards like SwiftKey (in identical scenarios).

`-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {...}`

For example:

The moment after I type: "ABCDEFG HIJ " without quotes and including the ending space using the stock keyboard, I find the `range` is equal to (11, 0). However, with SwiftKey, I'm getting a range of (10, 1). Additionally, the `text` will be equal to just the ending space using the stock keyboard, but will be equal to 'J' plus the space using SwiftKey. Any ideas why this is happening and how I can standardize my function's behavior given these differences if I want to properly detect certain phrases? (my goal is detecting the two words immediately before every space press)

EDIT: this is how I detect the two words in front of a space. *My issue is that **range** is giving me different values when I use a non-stock keyboard*

```
            NSUInteger charsBackUntilSecondSpace = 0;
            NSUInteger numSpacesFound = 0;
            for (int i = (int) range.location - 1; i>= 0; i--) {
                if([textView.text characterAtIndex:i] == ' ') {
                    numSpacesFound++;
                }
                if (numSpacesFound == 2) {
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    charsBackUntilSecondSpace++;
                }
            }

            UITextRange *selectedTextRange = textView.selectedTextRange;
            NSUInteger location = [textView offsetFromPosition:textView.beginningOfDocument
                                                    toPosition:selectedTextRange.start];
            NSRange inFrontOfCursorRange = NSMakeRange (location - charsBackUntilSecondSpace, charsBackUntilSecondSpace);
```

Answer (score 0):

> my goal is detecting the two words immediately before every space
>   press

You can achieve it like that below:-

```
NSInteger lenPos=(range.length > 2) ? 2 : range.length;
NSString *txt=[textView.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(range.length-lenPos-1, lenPos)] ;
```

Comment: Hi Hussain - detecting the two words immediately before every space press isn't my issue, it's the fact that the range value I'm getting when using a custom keyboard is different than when I'm using the stock keyboard.